# How to pass the parameters from a user-defined to delegate method in objective C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, parameter-passing

I want to ask about the passing parameter in objective C on iPhone simulator. 
Is it possible to pass an parameter (e.g. NSArray) to the delegate method?

I wrote a program, when the user press a button, it will call a function called 'pressLoginButton' (user-defined). After complete the function, I have to pass an NSArray and NSString to the delegate method (connectionDidFinishLoading() in NSURLConnection class). Is it possible to do it?

Comment: OK. I really have no idea what you're asking, but please. There is no such thing as `connectionDidFinishLoading()`, and it certainly is not part of the `NSURLConnection` class. What you are looking for is `-[NSObject(NSURLConnectionDelegate) connectionDidFinishLoading:]`, which means: the method `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` on the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` informal protocol (a category on `NSObject`). After you get your semantics right, please try to rephrase your question so that it makes sense. We want to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self setSavedProp:@"somevalue"];
```

since the delagate is "self", you can set a property on the current object/self/delegate

now in `connectionDidFinishLoading()`, access the property which contains the value you wanted

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   // doSomething with value...
   [self savedProp];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible. Only problem can be with memory management (retain/release), if isn't properly handled.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how to do it? Would you mind to give me a example for refer?